# How to calculate time missing

Tags: microsoft-excel

Heres the deal need attendance report that automatically emails if a person reaches so many hours absent in Excel.  I have VBA script that will email if a value is met.  I can't figure out a formula to calculate hours absent.  Thinking if formula =If A4 is less than 8 subtract 8 from A4 and then sum all hours. I keep getting -8, can someone help me out?

```
    IF(D3,"8",">8")-D3-8        D3 is 7.5 keep getting -7.5 should be .5
```

Comment: No. But if you add some sample data we can have a look for you.

Comment: Some diagrams or screen shots of your data would help us understand your question. Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question. Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Answer (score 0):

You keep getting `-7.5` because of the formula you are using:

```
=IF(D3,"8",">8")
```

will always return `"8"` if D3 has any number in it.  Excel sees any number > 0 as TRUE.

So we get

```
="8" - 7.5 - 8
```

`8-7.5=.5` then `.5 - 8 = -7.5`

My guess is you want:

```
=MAX(0,8 - D3)
```

Which if D3 is less the 8 it will return the difference in this case `.5` if it is equal to or greater than 8 it will return `0`